# Solve::nsmet system equations

Tags: equation-solving, warning-messages

```
A = Exp[-I*x] - Exp[-I*fi] Exp[I*x];
B2 = a21 + Exp[-I*x]*a20;
C2 = Cos[Theta] (a10 - a20);
DD = Exp[-2 I*fi] Exp[-I*x] - Exp[-I*fi] Exp[I*x];
B1 = Exp[-2 I*fi] (a11 - a10*Exp[-I*x]);
C1 = Cos[Theta] (a00 - a20);
EE = Exp[-I*fi] Exp[-I*x] - Exp[I*x];
B0 = Exp[-I*fi] (a01 - a00*Exp[-I*x]);
C0 = Cos[Theta] (a20 - a10);
Solve[
  F2 == (B2 + C2 + Cos[Theta]*(F0 - F1))/A & 
  F1 == (B1 + C1 + Cos[Theta]*(F2 - F0))/D & 
  F0 == (B0 + C0 + Cos[Theta]*(F1 - F2))/E, 
  {F1, F2, F0}]
```

> Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve. >>

What's the problem?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: This error message means that `Solve` does not know how to solve this set of equations.  Indeed, many equations do not have closed-for solutions.  Would it meet your needs to obtain a numerical answer?

Comment: I think you want `And` instead of `Function` -- i.e, `&&` instead of `&`.

Comment: I think you want DD in that denominator and not D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewriting your code with `&` corrected to `&&` and with parameters given in a more consistent manner

```
B0 = Exp[-I*fi] (a01 - a00*Exp[-I*x]);
B1 = Exp[-2 I*fi] (a11 - a10*Exp[-I*x]);
B2 = a21 + Exp[-I*x]*a20;
C0 = Cos[Theta] (a20 - a10);
C2 = Cos[Theta] (a10 - a20);
C1 = Cos[Theta] (a00 - a20);
AA = Exp[-I*x] - Exp[-I*fi] Exp[I*x];
DD = Exp[-2 I*fi] Exp[-I*x] - Exp[-I*fi] Exp[I*x];
EE = Exp[-I*fi] Exp[-I*x] - Exp[I*x];

Short[
  Solve[
    F2 == (B2 + C2 + Cos[Theta]*(F0 - F1))/AA &&
    F1 == (B1 + C1 + Cos[Theta]*(F2 - F0))/DD && 
    F0 == (B0 + C0 + Cos[Theta]*(F1 - F2))/EE,
    {F1, F2, F0}], 
  6]
```

gives the following solution:

[image: solution]